# Coalescing lvalue references to std-optionals

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic, optional

I want to coalesce (lvalue references to) optionals of the same type, in C++17:

```
#include <optional>

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... optionals );

template <typename T>
constexpr std::optional<T>& coalesce(std::optional<T>& x, std::optional<T>& y)
{
    return x.has_value() ? x : y;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr std::optional<T> coalesce(std::optional<T>& x)
{
    return x;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::optional<T> coalesce(std::optional<T>& x, std::optional<Ts>&... xs )
{
    return coalesce(x, coalesce(std::forward<std::optional<T>&>(xs)...));
}
```

This is sub-optimal, as it uses recursive templated function calls, rather than ellipsis-based expansion in a single body. What would you suggest?

Notes:

- C++17 and no fancy libraries please.
- This can be seen as a specific case of the "return first parameter in a pack satisfying a predicate", with the predicate being `[](auto x) { return x.has_value(); }`
- If possible, let's not copy any `T`'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So ideally you want to write something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constepxr auto coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... xs)
{
   return (xs || ...);
}
```

But the issue here is of course that it will convert the optionals to `bool` before applying the boolean or-operator. You could however cast it to a type that does provide the right semantics for the boolean or-operator to do the thing you want:

```
template <typename T>
struct coalescable {
    T &x;
    coalescable(T &x_): x(x_) {}
    constexpr const coalescable &operator||(const coalescable &other) {
        return x.has_value() ? *this : other;
    }
};
```

And then use that in the fold expression:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constepxr auto coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... xs)
{
   return (coalescable(xs) || ...).x;
}
```

Comment: It's too bad we can't define templated classes within functions.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica There is no problem an additional level of indirection cannot solve.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica we can't?

Comment: @NooneAtAll: Lambdas excluded from that statement obviously, but - no, we can't.

Comment: Nice solution! Just a small nitpick: The original code returned `std::optional<T>&` (note the reference!), but your final example returns the optionals by value (since `auto` doesn't deduce references). This can easily be fixed by changing the return type of `coalesce` to `auto&` (preferred in this case) or `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @hoffmale: only the function that takes two optionals, the one with the parameter pack returns by value in the original code. But yes, it's easy to change it to return `auto &`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: But that was actually a bug of mine... all functions are supposed to return references. I thought of changing this but I know it's frowned upon on CodeReview so I didn't :-(

Answer (score 9):

Folding? Bah. New-fangled nonsense. Real programmers use for loops for for looping.

```
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

template<class T, class... Ts>
std::optional<T> coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... xs)
{
    for (auto const& x : { std::reference_wrapper<std::optional<T>>(xs)... })
        if (x.get().has_value())
            return x;

    return {};
}
```

(Yeah, G. Sliepen's is better, and I still don't understand that other one).

Comment: Upvote for making me laugh with "real programmers". There is just one fly in the ointment: You require a manually specified return-type.

Comment: You can use the trick of @Deduplicator and write `using T = std::common_type_t<Ts...>`, so you can drop `class T` from the template arguments, and then use `auto` return type.

Comment: So, in what ways (other than elegance) is @G.Sliepen's answer better? IIANM yours would work with C++14 and and `std::experimental::optional`, wouldn't it?

Comment: I haven't seen a real programmers statement in decades! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you don't want recursion, you have to [fold](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead.

```
template <class... Ts>
constexpr auto coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... xs) {
    std::optional<std::common_type_t<Ts...>> r;
    ((xs && (r = xs, true)) || ...);
    return r;
}
```

If you want to avoid even the single copy to the result, you need to change the result-type by using an optional [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) or going with a potentially null pointer.

```
template <class... Ts>
constexpr auto coalesce(std::optional<Ts>&... xs) noexcept {
    std::common_type_t<Ts...>* r = nullptr;
    ((xs && (r = &*xs, true)) || ...);
    if (r)
        return std::optional(std::ref(*r));
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Aren't you copying T's here? I didn't forbid it but it seems like it's better to avoid that.

Comment: I was a bit confused about this at first too. But `r` is only assigned to once, and return value optimization avoids it from being a temporary copy. Of course it still returns a copy of one of the inputs, but so did your original code. I think all answers here could be modified to return a reference to one of the inputs, if that is what you want.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: That's actually a bug in my code! I should have consistently returned references. Also, regardless - shouldn't `r` here be made a reference wrapper?

Comment: Only if `coalesce()` should return a reference does `r` have to be a reference wrapper.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica If you really want to avoid even the copy to return-value, that needs `std::reference_wrapper` or returning a pointer. Your choice, added such an alternative.